# SVG stroke not showing inside of clipPath

Tags: reactjs, svg, border, stroke

I have the following [Codepen](https://codepen.io/A7DC/pen/KJgjKg?editors=0010), where I'm trying to animate a stroke of a circle around an image.

So far, I've got a circle SVG which is clipping an image, but it doesn't show the stroke inside of clipPath.

How do I get the border to show?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <svg width='48' height='48'>
        <defs>
          <clipPath id='circleView'>
            <circle cx='24' cy='24' r='23' fill='none' stroke='red' strokeWidth='2' />
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <image width='48' height='48' xlinkHref={'https://source.unsplash.com/random'} clipPath='url(#circleView)' />
      </svg>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: [the raw geometry of each child element exclusive of rendering properties such as ‘fill’, ‘stroke’, ‘stroke-width’ within a ‘clipPath’ conceptually defines a 1-bit mask (with the possible exception of anti-aliasing along the edge of the geometry) which represents the silhouette of the graphics associated with that element](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#EstablishingANewClippingPath)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Robert said, the child SVG figures in the `clip-path` line are not displayed.

Therefore, for the animation you need to add another circle outside the `clip-path`

`<circle cx="25" cy="24" r="14" fill="none" stroke="red" strokeWidth="2" />`

```css
.container {
    width:25%;
 height:25%;
   }
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <svg  viewBox="0 0 48 48" >
        <defs>
          <clipPath id='circleView'>
            <circle cx='24' cy='22' r='16' fill='none' stroke='red' stroke-width='2' />
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <image width="100%" height="100%"   xlink:href='https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9eO8.jpg' 
       clip-path='url(#circleView)' />
  <circle cx='24' cy='22' r='16' fill='none' stroke='red' strokeWidth='2' /> 
</svg>
  </div>
```

To animate a circle, use the change in the `stroke-dashoffset` attribute from maximum to zero. `values="(100.48;0)"`

*Animation starts after click*

```css
.container {
    width:25%;
 height:25%;
   }
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id='circleView'>
     <circle cx='24' cy='22' r='16' fill='none' stroke='red' stroke-width='2' />
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href='https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9eO8.jpg' clip-path='url(#circleView)' />
 <circle  transform="rotate(-90 24 22)" cx="24" cy="22" r="16" fill='none' stroke='red' strokeWidth='2' 
      stroke-dasharray="100.48"   stroke-dashoffset="100.48" >
            <animate
              attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
              dur="1s"
              begin="svg1.click"
              values="100.48;0"
              fill="freeze"/>
 </circle>  
      </svg>

  </div>
```

### Variant of animation with `CSS`

I added transparency animation to the circle animation.

*The animation begins when you hover the mouse cursor.*

```css
.container {
    width:25%;
 height:25%;
   }  
   #crc1 {
   fill:skyblue;
   stroke-width:1;
   stroke:red;
   stroke-dasharray:100.48;
   stroke-dashoffset:100.48;
    fill-opacity:0.9;
     }
   
   #crc1:hover {
    animation: dash 1.5s ease-out forwards;
      }
   
    @keyframes dash {
  0% { stroke-dashoffset: 100.48; fill-opacity:0.9; }
  50% { fill-opacity:0.45;}
  100% { stroke-dashoffset: 0; fill-opacity:0; }
   }
   
   #img1 {
   clip-path: url(#circleView);
     }
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id='circleView'>
            <circle cx='24' cy='22' r='16'/>
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href='https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9eO8.jpg' 
       clip-path='url(#circleView)' />
         <circle id="crc1"   cx="24" cy="22" r="16" />
          
      </svg>

  </div>
```